# I am Unable to run the openMP program

Tags: c++, openmp

```
#include "omp.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    omp_set_num_threads(4);
}
```

I am using this command to run the code `g++ -fopenmp program.cpp -o program`

The error is occurring when I use the above command.
`c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lpthread`

I also tried `g++ -fopenmp -pthread program.cpp -o program` but still working. This give the following error
`` C:\Users\aligr\AppData\Local\Temp\cckGZ0w8.o:c.cpp:(.text+0x16): undefined reference to `omp_set_num_threads' collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status ``

Comment: Are you trying to parallelize matrix multiplication using openmp?

Comment: Much more information is required before anyone can help. 
Which OS (and version) are you using? (It looks like Windows, but that is a large field!). 
What environment? (A shell, a GUI, ...). 
Which version of GCC?
How was it installed? 
How is your environment set up?